# Confused about pipes: (Making a "3 commands pipe".)

Tags: command-line, pipe, lsof

So I have to make a pipe which consists of 3 commands:

1. A program written in **c** that prints a text in an infinite loop - 
   after compiling it's called `a.out`
2. it could be anything, for example `xcalc`
3. as above, for example `xclock`

So my question is how can I make a pipe with those 3 things and then use command `lsof` to get any information about the pipe that is opened?
I tried something like this:

```
mknod pipe1 p ./a.out | xclock | xcalc
```

but it doesn't work properly.
Which argument do I have to use with `lsof` to get the information that I want? (In *Solaris* it is `pfiles -F`).

Comment: Are you trying to pipe the output of `a.out` to both `xclock` and `xcalc`?

Comment: It was just an example but is this a thing that I shouldn't do? Tbh I don't know exactly which two other commands I can use in this pipe, the first command which prints a text must be there, and the other two might be anything so at first i thought about xcalc and xclock.

Comment: Right, I don't really care what the other two are, I'm asking what you're goal is.  Are you trying to have the output of `a.out` go to 2 different programs, or do you want its output to go to a single program, then the output of that to go to the next one

Comment: Ok, but I still don't know what your task is.  That's what I'm trying to find out.  You say your command "doesn't work properly"  What about it doesn't work?  What did you want to have happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: The command to the task, that I got from my professor is: 
Using the appropriate program explore the open files of each of the processes involved in the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Just as in plumbing, physical pipes must have two open ends, (e.g. one side where water goes *in*, and one side where water goes *out*), in **nix* pipes require programs that either receive input from `/dev/stdin`, (i.e. *standard input*), and send output to `/dev/stdout`, (i.e. *standard output*), or (more often) do both.  Programs which are designed to do neither of these things behave like *plugs* or stoppers do in plumbing, stopping the flow, (of data).

All three of the programs used in the OP, (`mknod`, `xclock`, and `xcalc`), don't use *stdin* or *stdout* enough to matter, and are therefore the **nix* equivalent of *plugs*.  Piping them together would be no more useful than connecting three Idaho potatoes with two lengths of PVC pipe.

Comment: Actually, my guess is that `xclock` and `xcalc` would be just fine for the purpose of the exercise.  But the question is too confused to be answerable at this point (in comments it has switched to named pipes, notice) and that's just my educated guess as to the purpose behind the professor setting this task.

Comment: Ok I get it. So let's forgot about named pipe. I wrote a script that prints 'cat' in the terminal every 3 seconds. Is this a good use of the pipe?
./pipe1.sh | sed -e 's/cat/dog/'

Comment: @JdeBP, I believe we should help the confused student; inferring what his professor may have said seems uncertain at best.   I also noticed the `mknod`, but this student isn't ready for `mknod` yet.

Comment: @Ensz, no, *a script that prints 'cat' in the terminal every 3 seconds* is not likely to be an instructive use of pipes.  Instead of *asking* here,  start *testing* things yourself.  I suggest first deciding which programs produce only output, (i.e. `seq`, `yes`, etc.), which programs act as filters, (i.e. `head`, `grep`, etc.), and which programs receive input and report on it, (i.e. `wc`, etc.).

Comment: We don't need to infer what the professor said.  That has turned up, buried in comments, already.  There's no uncertainty about that.

Comment: @JdeBP, as you please.  IMHO:  confused student <> reliable narrator.